# Know if the form had validation errors in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that I submit via AJAX. It is using the standard MVC validation. When the user first loads the page, this form is hidden. It only appears after the users click on a button in the page.

I want to know if there is a way to know --in the view-- if there were errors in the validation. So, the next time the form is displayed, the form is being shown and not hidden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could *know it* like this:

```
if ($('#someFormId').valid()) {
    // the form is valid
} else {
    // the form contains validation errors
}
```

or if you wanted to test if there are some mode errors in the view:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // there are no errors to display
} else {
    // there were validation errors
}
```

Comment: Is this javascript?? I meant during the View creation.

Comment: @tou, yeah, pure javascript. I have updated my answer to illustrate how to do this server side.

Comment: That's jQuery, not pure JavaScript.